# VS Code settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to change the following VS code behavior but can't find a way to do so:

1. When the cursor is on some items a box pops up with info about that item. I find this extremely annoying as it often blocks what I'm trying to edit. How to disable the pop up?
2. I code CSS on a single line, such as:
   `h1 {something;  something;  something; }`  And the next CSS on the next line. No Spaces!
   But when I save it VS code automatically reformulates it, putting each something on a new line. This is extremely, extremely annoying!  It horribly wastes space, and forces me to scroll down a lot to find something I want to edit. How do I get VS code to stop messing with My Coding Style?

Comment: 1. You said it's annoying for the pop up, but normally that's very useful. (General opinion)      2. If you want to keep the CSS statements on different line then `disable` or `uninstall` the `CSS formatting extension` if you have downloaded it.

Comment: Another thing is it's totally very very bad coding style for writing in one line. Keeping in different lines enhances readability. If you keep on writing like that, it would be very difficult on the long run. People also like neatly written, indented and formatted code. Not just compacted code.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm wrong. 

Answer (score 0):

1. To disable the pop up. Do these necessary changes [Disable pop up](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://blog.shawnhyde.com/post/2019/02/16/how-to-disable-popup-tips-in-visual-studio-code&ved=2ahUKEwihg4nomfbzAhU2zDgGHaKNDjUQFnoECAQQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1XwByPAFgVXpH4k1SIvJzU)
2. To stop the CSS formatting, just see in the extensions if you have downloaded CSS formatter, if so then uninstall it or disable it.